# Please help me find Prior Art for US20130100291 A1

Tags: prior-art-request, us20130100291

Prior Art Request for US20130100291 A1

```
Publication number  US20130100291 A1
Publication type    Application
Application number  US 13/654,728
Publication date    Apr 25, 2013
Filing date         Oct 18, 2012
Priority date       Oct 21, 2011
Also published as   EP2584425A1
Inventors           Chee Seng Tan, Rahunandan KANDASAMY, Tee Meng PANG
Original Assignee   Wincor Nixdorf International Gmbh
Export Citation     BiBTeX, EndNote, RefMan
```